# SonarQube GitHub Plugin on Automatic Pull Requests

Tags: automation, sonarqube, git-pull

SonarQube helps to highlight all SONAR violations and in the analysis of each Pull Request code change when done on the local system.

Is there any option/set-up where I can automate any Pull Request to be analyzed by SonarQube in GIT and send out an email or update a dashboard with the latest SONAR code violations? All I want is to automate the SONAR analysis as soon as someone initiates a pull request.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do any googling? Have you read the sonarqube docs?

Comment: I have provided the detail answer with example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047585/jenkins-sonar-github-integration

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a third component namely the CI server.  This is the TL;DR solution for is how I did it full version in https://www.trajano.net/2016/11/integrating-travis-sonarqube/

1. Create tokens for your account in SonarQube.com accounts security.
2. Create a GitHub personal access token with repo access.
3. Enable Travis build for your repository.
4. Create a .travis.yml file.

```
    language: java
    jdk:
      - oraclejdk8
    sudo: false
    cache:
      directories:
      - "$HOME/.m2"
      - "$HOME/.sonar/cache"
    addons:
      sonarqube: true
    install:
    - mvn dependency:go-offline
    script:
    - mvn install site -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
    after_success:
    - mvn sonar:sonar
```

5. Add the tokens using travis encrypt

```
    travis encrypt SONAR_TOKEN=[token from sonarqube.com]
    travis encrypt SONAR_GITHUB_TOKEN=[token from github.com]
```