# jenkins gradle sonar -> github comments

Tags: github, jenkins, gradle, sonarqube

I'd like to have sonar comments on github pull requests. For that I set up a jenkins job which runs `./gradlew clean sonarRunner [properties]`.
I read through this:
[jenkins + sonar + github integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047585/jenkins-sonar-github-integration)

My setup is similar, I don't start sonar with maven but with gradle.
I use the following properties:

```
-Dsonar.github.login=
-Dsonar.github.repository=company/repo
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview 
-Dsonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true 
-Dsonar.github.login=gitusername 
-Dsonar.github.oauth=token
```

As described here: 
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin

The end of the log on jenkins is:

> 11:06:02.167 INFO  - Sensor GitHub Plugin InputFile Cache 
>   11:06:02.167 INFO  - Sensor GitHub Plugin InputFile Cache (done) | time=0ms 
>   11:06:02.168 INFO  - Load server issues 
>   11:06:02.532 INFO  - 
>    
>   -------------  Issues Report  -------------
>
> ```
>   +620 issues
>
>     +2 blocking
>    +43 critical
>   +402 major
>   +169 minor
>     +4 info
> ```
>
> ---
>
> 11:06:02.532 INFO  - Export issues to
>   /jenkins/workspace/scheduling-sonar-pull-request/jdk/JDK8/label/Linux/build/sonar/sonar-report.json 
>   11:06:02.611 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
>
> INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS INFO:
>
> Total time: 20.198s Final Memory: 26M/742M INFO:
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL

But there are no comments appearing on github.

In order to debug changed the oauth token, which gave:

> ERROR: Caused by: Unable to perform GitHub WS operation 
>   ERROR: Caused by: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:

Why are no comments appearing on github? The github plugin is installed on sonarqube, jenkins triggers the sonarRunner, the PR id is correct (tried it hard-coded), the PR has a lot of files, a wrong oauth token gives an error.

Comment: Updating to version 5.1.2 solved the issue.

Comment: updating what to 5.1.2 fixed it?

Comment: Updating sonar to version 5.1.2 solved the issue