# sonar jenkins github integration

Tags: github, jenkins, sonarqube

In reference with the post 
[jenkins + sonar + github integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047585/jenkins-sonar-github-integration)

What setting is required in sonarqube? Does Sonar and Jenkins reside on the same box? How will Sonarqube be able to communicate with github? I am able to get the pull request triggering the Jenkins Job which is calling the sonar analysis, but the sonar comments are not getting added back to github. I am able to add the Jenkins build status but not the sonar analysis . Can someone point to the right direction

Comment: have you followed http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095346/5052331 ? you question is too vague. What have you done? What are the error messages? What doesn't work? Which plugins have you installed?

Comment: I have installed sonarqube runner, sonaqube plugin in Jenkins. I have also installed github plugin in sonarqube. When running the jenkins job with sonar:sonar and analysis as preview, expectation was the results to be logged back to github,the parameters also have github pull request number, github org and repo and all params mentioned in the post i followed. "jenkins + sonar + github integration"

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube don't need to communicate with GitHub.
Jenkins have a plugin "Git-Plugin" used to connect with it, you only have to paste the repository url there.
Jenkins have a plugin "SonarQube Plugin" used to call sonarQube, this will return a status after sonnar analysis.
Then you can create another task in Jenkins to makes changes in GitHub according to the status.